# How do I filter Directory.GetFiles() by a numeric range when file names are listed in numeric order?

Tags: c#, search, directory, getfiles

I want filter which files are getting returned from the Directory.GetFiles() function. The files in the directory are all text files named with 6 digit numbers in incremental order (for example: "200501.txt", "200502.txt", "200503.txt", and so on), I would like to enter a "Starting Invoice Number" and "Ending Invoice Number" through 2 text box controls to return only the files within that range.

The current code is as follows...

```
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                string[] fileDir = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath);
                string[] files = fileDir;

                foreach (string loopfile in files)
                {
                    int counter = 0;
                    string line;
                    //Gets invoice number from text file name
                    //This strips all unnecessary strings out of the directory and file name
                    //need to change substring 32 to depending directory using
                    string loopfileName = loopfile.Substring(32);
                    string InvoiceNumberLong = Path.GetFileName(loopfile);
                    string InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumberLong.Substring(0,(InvoiceNumberLong.Length - 4)).ToString();
                    var controlCount = new List<string>();
                    var EndCount = new List<string>();

                    //Read through text file line by line to find all instances of "control" and "------" string
                    //adds all line position of these strings to lists
                    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(loopfile);
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("Control"))
                        {
                            controlCount.Add(counter.ToString());
                        }
                        if (line.Contains("------"))
                        {
                            EndCount.Add(counter.ToString());
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the built in filter that the GetFiles method provides, that can only filter by wild cards. You can do it with some LINQ:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt")
       .Where(d => int.TryParse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d), out var value) && value > min && value < max);
```

Note: Using C#7 out var but can be converted to previous versions if you are not using the latest.

Comment: Also consider using `EnumerateFiles` rather than `GetFiles`.

Comment: Yes you are right, `EnumerateFiles` is better changed the answer to reflect this

Comment: Thanks I will look into this and give it a try now!

Comment: @MegaByteMe, glad to help, don't forget to mark as answered if it was the answer you were looking for ;)